# GUI with multiple sliders

Tags: matlab

I have an equation that depends of 8 Variables and there are 8 sliders wich define each variable. Until now I have started the calculation of the equation with a pushbutton and it has been ploted. 
I want that the GUI makes the calculation without a pushbutton and everytime that I change the value of any slider the solution is automatically updated in the plot. 
This is the code that I have been using so far:

```
 function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
 % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
 % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 T = get(handles.sliderT, 'value');
 x0=get(handles.sliderx0,'value');
 kSin=get(handles.sliderkSin,'value');
 kSigma=get(handles.sliderkSigma,'value');
 Omega=get(handles.slideromega,'value');
 alpha=get(handles.slideralpha,'value')*180/pi;
 t0=get(handles.slidert0,'value');
 tspan = [0 50];
 xprimefixed = @(t,x) xprime(t,x,T,kSin,kSigma,Omega,alpha,t0);
 [t,x] = ode45(xprimefixed, tspan, x0);
 plot(handles.axes2, t, x, 'g');
```

Could any body give an advice on where to put the code in order to eliminate the push button?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The function currently in the pushbutton callback is what does the calculation.

I suggest you rename `pushbutton1_Callback(~,~,handles)` to `runODE(handles)`, and add `runODE(handles)` to the end of the callback of each slider. Thus, each slider movement will result in a call to `runODE`.

What would be even nicer design-wise is to have `runODE` only read the values out of the GUI, and have  a separate function accept all those values and return `x` and `t`, which you can then plot within the GUI. Thus, you can easily use (and test) the ODE function without needing to start the GUI, for example if you want to perform an exhaustive parameter sweep.

Comment: So if I get it right, should I just change the name of the push button function like this: function runODE(handles) and bellow wright all the previous code and at the slider callback just wright  at the end runODE(handles)??

Comment: @HenriqueZingg: Exactly.